# Lock axis in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I've used ZedGraph to plot data from several sources with a single click. I need the Y-axes to always have the same max and min-values for each plot. I need this to be able to see changes between datasets as I flip through them. In my case, it would not make sense to plot data from several sources in one graph.

I've tried to set axis properties like this:

```
    myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.Max = 40;
    myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.MaxAuto = false;
    myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.Min = -40;
    myPane.Y2Axis.Scale.MinAuto = false;
```

I still see the axes beeing auto scaled. Please give me a hint if this is possible or not. I probably only miss a small thing...

(by the way: I hope someone picks this project up, it's great!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, solved like this:

```
        zGC.AxisChange();
        zGC.RestoreScale(myPane);
        zGC.ZoomOut(myPane);
```

Added a ZoomOut(), since I realized that RestoreScale() actually always autozooms...

-rb

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to synchronize the scales of all panes that you use? 
If so, have you seen [this tutorial](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Synchronize_Scrolling_on_a_MasterPane)?

The second thing is that the `Y2Axis` is not visible by default. ZG uses by default first Y axis (`YAxis`). Have you enabled `Y2Axis` manually?