# zed graph: how to make my graph start at 0,0

Tags: c#, sql, plot, zedgraph

I want my graph to start at 0,0 but right now it is starting at the time that the data starts (because i don't know what a better alternative for xdatamember would be to get my desired results. any suggestions?

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
        commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource.DataSource = table;

        // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
        dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        // you can make it grid readonly.
        dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
        // finally bind the data to the grid
        dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;
        GraphPane myPane = height.GraphPane;

        // Create a new DataSourcePointList to handle the database connection
        DataSourcePointList dspl = new DataSourcePointList();

        // Specify the table as the data source
        dspl.DataSource = table;

        dspl.XDataMember = "age";
        dspl.YDataMember = "height";

        LineItem Curve1 = myPane.AddCurve("student 1", dspl, Color.pink, SymbolType.None);
        height.AxisChange();
        myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightGray, 45.0F);

        // set the title and axis labels
        myPane.Title.Text = "student heights";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "age";
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "height";

        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I did a quick search for this sort of thing and found this: [Lock axis in ZedGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681414/lock-axis-in-zedgraph)

You can set the XAxis.Min and YAxis.Min to whichevers value you want shown as the min of the respective Axes.  My code from my test looked like this:

```
//static ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl graph = new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl();
ZedGraph.GraphPane pane = graph.GraphPane;
pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0.0;
graph.AxisChange();
graph.RestoreScale(pane);
graph.ZoomOut(pane);
```

Comment: Good answer. Just want to add that in normal cases, in particular the initialization phase, setting axes `Scale.Min = 0.0` and `pane.AxisChange()` or `graph.AxisChange()` is enough; `RestoreScale` and `ZoomOut` are redundant (at least in initial setup).